# Transform flat array to multidimensional with node values

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this (changed to food for the example - it's actually a taxonomy of business topic tags):

```
Array
(
    [fruit] => Fruit
    [fruit/apple] => Apple
    [fruit/banana] => Banana
    [fruit/passion-fruit] => Passion fruit
    [vegetable] => Vegetable
    [vegetable/beans] => Beans
    [vegetable/beans/runner-beans] => Runner beans        
)
```

I'd like to use recursion (presumably) to change it into this:

```
Array
(
    [fruit] => Array
        (
            [title] => Fruit
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [apple] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Apple
                        )
                    [banana] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Banana
                        )
                    [passion-fruit] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Passion fruit
                        )
                )
        )
    [vegetable] => Array
        (
            [title] => Vegetable
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [beans] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => Beans
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [runner-beans] => Array
                                        (
                                            [title] => Runner beans
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I can't figure out how to do it. I've found other examples here for converting flattened arrays into multidimensional ones but not where there's a value ('Title') and a custom child node. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your array is named `$array`:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $temp =& $result;
    $path = explode('/', $key);

    foreach($path as $subkey) {
        if(!isset( $temp[$subkey])) {
            $temp[$subkey]['title'] = $value;
            $temp[$subkey]['children'] = array();
        }
        $temp =& $temp[$subkey]['children'];
    }
}
```

I am posting this even though it creates a `children` key even when there are no children.  I will revisit and edit.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. Simple when I see it written down - the 'by reference' passing makes total sense now. If you are able to remove the empty children node, even better!

Comment: Out of interest, if instead of the array key being the 'ID', we had a indexed array like [0] => array('id' => 'orange', 'title' => 'Orange', children => ...), how simple would that be to do? I know we're using a isset() on the key name so it might introduce complexity having to search within the array.